# Projection matrix onto a subspace parallel to a complementary subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Given an $n \times k$ matrix $A$ and an $n \times (n-k)$ matrix $B$ such that $\text{span}(A) \oplus \text{span}(B) = \mathbb{R}^n$, how to get the projection matrix on $\text{span}(A)$ parallel to $\text{span}(B)$, in terms of $A$ and $B$?

---

Edit:

Below it is worked out that $P=\Big(\big(^−^ (^ )^{−1}^  \big)^{−1} ^ − (^ )^{−1}^  \big(^−^(^)^{−1}^ 
\big)^{-1}^ \Big)$.

- Does it look right?
- Can we possibly simplify it?
- Is the horrendous look the reason that we rarely see it fleshed out in textbooks, etc.?

---

Edit 2:

I have verified numerically that the formula is correct. Also, with SVD $A = U_A \Sigma_A V_A^T$, $B = U_B \Sigma_B V_B^T$ and $U_{AB} = U_A^T U_B$, 
it can be simplified that $P = U_A \Big(I - U_{AB}^T U_{AB} \Big)^{-1} U_A^T - U_A U_{AB} \Big(I - U_{AB}^T U_{AB} \Big)^{-1}U_B^T$.

But I have little intuition on how to understand the expression. If anyone can provide some, that'd be great.

Comment: Hint: In a suitable basis, the matrix has the block form $\small{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&0\\ \hline 0&0\end{array}\right]}$.

Comment: Let $C = [A|B]$ and let $c_j$ be the $j$-th column of $C$. Let $U$ be the matrix with $Uc_j = e_j$ and denote by $\bar U$ the $k\times n$ upper part of $U$. Then $P = A\bar U$. Indeed, $A\bar Ua_j = Ae_j = a_j$ and $A\bar Ub_i = A(0) = 0$.

Comment: Can we express $P$ in terms of $A$ and $B$? (Question edited.)

Comment: Yes. See my answer below.

Comment: There is an ordering error in the $U_{AB}$ terms in the first $(\ldots)^{-1}$ subexpression. The correct projector is 
$$P = U_A \Big(I - U_{AB} U_{AB}^T \Big)^{-1} U_A^T \;-\; U_A U_{AB} \Big(I - U_{AB}^T U_{AB} \Big)^{-1}U_B^T$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U = [A|B]^{-1}$ and denote by $\bar U$ the $k\times n$ upper part of $U$. Then $P = A\bar U$. Indeed, since $\bar U[A|B] = \left[\begin{matrix}I_k&0\end{matrix}\right]$, we have $A\bar Ua_j = Ae_j = a_j$ and $A\bar Ub_i = A(0) = 0$.

Comment: If we work out the expression, $P = A \Big( \big( A^T A - A^T B (B^T B)^{-1} B^T A \big)^{-1} A^T - (A^T A)^{-1} A^T B \big( B^T B - B^T A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T B \big)^{-1} B^T \Big)$. Does it look right? Can we possibly simplify it? Is the horrendous look the reason that we rarely see it fleshed out in textbooks, etc.?

Comment: @Lei Duuude, how did you get to this super ugly expression? I'm curious.

Comment: I assumed $[A \; B]^{-1} = \big([A \; B]^T [A \; B]\big)^{-1} [A \; B]^T =    \begin{bmatrix} A^T A \quad A^T B \\ B^T A \quad B^T B\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} A^T \\ B^T \end{bmatrix}$. Then I used the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) for the inverse of block matrix. Is my first assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct because $(C^TC)^{-1}C^T = C^{-1}C^{-T}C^T = C^{-1}$.

Comment: Your expression might look ugly, but when it comes to numerically computing $P$, then it is probably better because the sizes of the matrices that have to be inverted might be much smaller. Can you please check my answer?